# can i use indexedDB in developing firefox Os applications

Tags: javascript, mozilla, indexeddb, github-api, firefox-os

I made an app for firefox-os which uses login functionality. I used indexedDB for local storage of username and password for future references. (Github Login)

But my app got rejected from Firefox marketplace as they say that they can't login on their phone `keon` and `unagi`. I have tested my app on `Firefox Simulator`. I'm able to login as well with my `Github account`.

Does `indexedDB` work in firefox-os smartphone as mentioned above? It's working fine in Firefox Simulator though.

Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the error stems from any differences in the indexedDB code.

I would recommend trying to debug the app on an actual Firefox OS device - if you can't afford one, I'm pretty sure your local mozilla community would help you out there, by letting you use one of their devices for testing purposes - until you manage to work out the kinks and find the root cause to the problem.

Unfortunately testing the app on a real device sometimes can not be avoided, as every simulated environment has its limitations.

My other advice would be, that you should ask the Firefox OS app developer community. If you have the app source code uploaded online somewhere (e.g. on GitHub), you should drop a mail on the [Mozilla Webapps Developer mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mozilla.dev.webapps) and ask people to have a look at your app, test it on a real device - maybe they can help you assess the problem.

Comment: Ah!, thanks for your reply, indexedDB works in firefox-os, i saw many apps. TODOS is one such among them :)
The problem was just a little misunderstanding about the login credentials.

Answer (score 1):

IndexedDB is available on all Firefox versions including the one in Firefox OS. In fact, many of the built-in app use it.

I know that because I am one of the developers :)

I would suggest you test your app with localhost server on desktop Firefox, where the debug tool is available; it would be much easier than blindly try things out in the simulator. That's actually what we do to :-/ only the UI and the layout matters in the simulator environment.

Comment: Yes, i tried it and even used it.
The real cause was just a misunderstanding regarding the login credentials.